# Error al guardar datos. Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un pequeño form donde tengo un `select` y un `input` para editar información de una de una tabla que tengo. Cuando quiero guardar los cambios me aparece un error en el `db.SaveChangesAsync()`

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
> number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
> entities were loaded

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EditSubCategoria([Bind(Include = "ServicioCategoriaId,Descripcion,Activo")] ServicioSubCategoria servicioSubCategoria)
        {

            List<string> errors = new List<string>();
            errors.Add("Error al guardar subcategoria");

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(servicioSubCategoria).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                errors.Add(ex.Message);
            }

            
            ViewBag.ServicioCategoriaId = new SelectList(db.ServicioCategorias, "ServicioCategoriaId", "Descripcion", servicioSubCategoria.ServicioCategoriaId);
            return View(servicioSubCategoria);
        }
```

Donde los datos los obtengo desde `ajax` (ya comprobé que los datos que edito y mando al controlador sean los mismos).

Comment: Intenta agregando el set attach antes del entry, `db.set<TuModelo>().Attach(servicioSubCategoria);`

Comment: Parece que si me sirvió pero ahora me dice que no se encuentra la vista `EditSubCategoria`

Comment: intenta cambiar  `return RedirectToAction("Index");` por `return view("nombre de tu vista");`, `redirectToAction` úsalo cuánto vas a redireccionar con parámetros , igual creo que deberías modificar tu pregunta y mostrar las vistas que tienes, porque index puede ser la vista principal de `EditSubCategoria`, o si quieres redireccionar a otro controlador, usa `Redirect("controlador/tuvista");`

Comment: Es que no me devuelve una vista, es solo una función que utilizo en un modal para editar y guardar información.

Comment: en tu codigo estás retornando a un vista, si es un modal, no es necesario retornar una vista, si no un mensaje que se realizó correctamente la actualización, igual creo que es mejor que edites tu pregunta para saber que es lo que deseas en realidad, pero tú pregunta ya fue respondida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En general el retorno esperado de una solicitud por AJAX es un JSON (no una vista), para eso puedes ocupar la función `Json(objeto)`, donde el objeto puedes ser del cualquier tipo, yo utilizaré un string

Luego para hacer un Update solo es necesario hacer `db.Update`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EditSubCategoria([Bind(Include = "ServicioCategoriaId,Descripcion,Activo")] ServicioSubCategoria servicioSubCategoria)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)) return Json("Error");

    try
    {
        db.Upadte(servicioSubCategoria);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return return Json("OK");
        
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Json("Error");
    }

}
```